# Can’t ping any server and connect to the internet

Tags: networking, kubuntu, iptables, tor

After I loaded toriptables 2 rules,it connects to internet but can’t ping any server even the router,I flushed all iptable rules,but still I cannot enter any server.I restarted my computer,restarted wlan0 but does not work.

Comment: Welcome! You can't even ping your router? Assuming it is your default gateway, please provide us some network debugging commands / tests you've done and their outputs so we can at least have some clue where to begin. Commands like "ifconfig", "IP A" or "route". You don't have to share your full IP addresses, assuming you're sure about the configurations.

Comment: Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         172.20.10.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth1
default         192.168.68.1    0.0.0.0         UG    20600  0        0 wlan0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 anbox0
172.20.10.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U     100    0        0 eth1
192.168.68.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0
192.168.250.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 anbox0